Python Requests_html :[D:websockets.client] infinite loop
    from requests_html import HTMLSession
    domain = 'www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZPZq0r_RZOOeQBaP5SeMjl2nwDcJaV0T&si=qvxo87GMVf5KGtla'
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(f'http://{domain}')
    try:
        r.html.render()
        print("Rendered successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during rendering: {e}")
    # Save the HTML content to a file
    with open('output.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(r.html.html)

    print("HTML content has been written to 'output.html'")

I have this simple code, I am discovering the requests_html library in python . I am trying to open the yt playlist and render it , but I am getting an infinite loop of these :
  [D:websockets.client] > %s [D:websockets.client] < %s
even thought I tried putting a timeout on the  r.html.render() didn't work.
Should this work ? or should I change the library? I know Selenium works but I was trying this one for this simple task
I was expecting to get the html of the  yt playlist, with the videos html loaded in it
